# Is this "согласитесь" the Future or the Imperative?

Tags: значения, глаголы

> **Согласитесь**, впечатляет: у ребенка, как я, свой бизнес!

This is what a kid said. Given the exclamation mark, it's tempting to regard it as the imperative form:

> "(You **must**) Agree(**!**) that it's impressive: a kid like me running his own business!"

---

Another interpretation -- the future tense -- seems possible as well, supposing that a question mark is hidden behind the colon:

> "You **will** agree that it's impressive, (**right?**): a kid like me running his own business!"

Then again, in English, the future tense "will" can be used like the imperative to give an order. As such, even if this "согласитесь" is the future tense, it may still be considered to be close in meaning to the imperative "согласитесь".

> {in an imperative tone} "You **will** agree that it's impressive: a kid like me running his own business!"

Answer (score 6):

> Согласитесь, впечатляет: у ребенка, как я, свой бизнес! (Правда,впечатляет--замена)

This is an introductory word.
There's a group of **introductory words** which express an appeal to the interlocutor (Розенталь, § 99)

```
>видишь (ли), видите (ли), понимаешь (ли), понимаете (ли), знаешь (ли), знаете (ли), пойми, поймите, поверьте, послушайте, согласитесь, согласись, вообразите, представьте себе, извините, простите, веришь (ли), верите (ли), пожалуйста
```

You shouldn't mix them with the similar grammatical forms of the imperative and the future, or present forms.(Here you cannot substitute another word at all)

How to distinguish :

You can change them with other introductory words, you cannot ask questions from other words in the sentence, you can leave them out, they are put in commas.

> Я думаю, вы согласитесь поработать с нами.(future)
>   Согласись со мной поехать, ну, пожалуйста.(imperative ).

Answer (score 3):

That's the ("clear") imperative form use case. The (tending to) future tense use would include some introducing words, e.g.: "Думаю, вы согласитесь, что..." (I think/believe you'll agree that...); "Ведь вы согласитесь, что..." (You'll surely agree that...).

Answer (score 1):

To determine the correct interpretation, we should check what happens when the verb is in singular.  Is it `согласись` (imperative) or `согласишься` (future tense) ?

The search for `согласись` in ruscorpora finds hunderds of such usages:

- Но вообще… согласись, ведь на самом деле всё так и есть!
- Согласись Сергей ― это история Выксы!! (comma is missing after `согласись`)
- Согласись, что эти в зале Академии выглядели примерно таким же образом, несмотря на дорогой прикид.
- ...ведь был прав, согласись.
- Но согласись, что мелодические линии этих оперных сцен не свойственны вагнеровскому мышлению.
- Согласись, после неудачи в Портофино группе было не до возлюбленной Кенаря...

The search for `согласишься` does not find such cases. In rare cases when `согласишься` means "you will agree with what I am saying", `ты` is always present, for example:

> Но ведь ты согласишься, любезный читатель, не правда ли, что между любовью и предательством существует определенная иерархия.

**Conclusion:** `согласитесь` in such sentences should be interpreted as an imperative.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is in the *Imperative* (despite the coincidence with the Future form) and the word literally invites to '*agree*' with the following statement. However, it is closer to something like '**Look, it's impressive..**.' '**You know, it's impressive...**' and is a bit more formal than **Hey, it's impressive!**